# React Project not setting up

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

while creating react project I got below error.

Command:
`npx create-react-app demo --use-npm`

Error:
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\akashroy8\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-07T11_10_29_520Z-debug-0.log

I was trying to create react project but I received the above errorr and it's creating the project more than 30 minutes.